# AzureMLCompute job failed: container registry failed unexpectedly: container setup task failed

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-machine-learning-service

Could you please help me with running python script in azureml environment? I created the workspace and azure container registry and pushed docker image to the container. This is the example of dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install virtualenv

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/venv

RUN virtualenv venv -p python3

ENV PATH="VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

ENV PYTHON_PACKAGES="\
numpy \
pandas \
seaborn \
matplotlib \
sklearn \
scipy \
imbalanced-learn \
xgboost \
joblib \
" 

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir $PYTHON_PACKAGES

ENTRYPOINT ["python3","train.py"]
```

I created environment like this:
`myenv = Environment.from_pip_requirements(name = ws.get_details()['name'],file_path = "requirements.txt")`

When I run the experiment I get this error:

`"Message": "AzureMLCompute job failed.\nJobContainerConfigFailed: Container configuration failed unexpectedly\n\tJobContainerConfigFailed: Container configuration failed unexpectedly\n\terr: container setup task failed: exit status 1\n\tReason: container setup task failed: exit status 1\n\tInfo: Failed to prepare an environment for the job execution: Job environment preparation failed on 10.0.0.5 with err exit status 1."`

I do not understand what this error mean.

I configure and submit training job with following:

```
    src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.',
                        script='train.py',
                        compute_target=cpu_cluster,
                        environment=myenv)
    
    #Submit training job
    run = Experiment(ws,'test-classification').submit(src)
    run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Moki,

Did you run the experiment in an Azure pipeline on DevOps? If so, please shared the detailed pipeline definition.
And have you tried the experiment on your local machine? Did the same issue occur?

Comment: Thank you Bright Ran-MSFT for your response! I managed to run locally from docker image, but failed with /bin/sh: 1: conda: not found when I try to run it when using azure ml environment locally.

Comment: Hi @Moki, make sure you have set up the required environment on your local machine. And use the same source files.